# RecyclerView duplicates every item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem dealing with recyclerview, when i return back to the activity after opening another activity, it duplicates all the items i displayed. Is there any way to fix this?

Like on list view, it just automatically clears the list and then display it again. can you show me how? thanks

> OnCreate

```
int x = 0;
                for(String Name : property_name){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = arrayResponse.getJSONObject(x);
                    property_id[x] = jsonObject.getString("property_id");
                    property_name[x] = jsonObject.getString("property_name");
                    type[x] = jsonObject.getString("property_type");
                    price[x] = jsonObject.getString("price");
                    address[x] = jsonObject.getString("address");

                    ListingNearby listingNearby = new ListingNearby(property_id[x], property_name[x], type[x], price[x], Math.round(distance[x]));
                    x++;
                    list.add(listingNearby);

                }

                recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ln_recycler_view);
                layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                adapter = new ListingNearbyAdapter(list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I wonder what to put in onResume so that the listview clears the list and then display it again.

Comment: Looks like you've messed up your `onResume`...

Comment: what should i put in onResume?

Comment: How could I help you when I have no idea what your code looks like?

Comment: i've update my question, i did it all in onCreate.

Comment: You've probably re-added the Object to your `list` somewhere. For now you could try adding `list.clear()` before the for loop and see how it goes. Unfortunately it's all guesswork with only that piece of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try to list.clear() before you begin your loop. I guess your list is kind of static variable.

Answer (score 1):

override these two method in your adapter:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return reviewModels.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

it worked for me